# Login View appears as logged but I'm not logged

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image: Problem using Login Controller]

I have a problem with Login View on Master Page.

When I login everything works fine, but if I close the tab for a while or I rebuild the application my session is closed but the login view still showing a Session :/.

I have this code in Site.Master

```
<div class="loginDisplay">
            <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                <AnonymousTemplate>
                    [ <a href="~/Login.aspx" id="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a>
                    ]
                </AnonymousTemplate>
                <LoggedInTemplate>
                    Bienvenido <span class="bold">
                   <%-- HeadLoginName--%>
                        <asp:LoginName ID="MemberName" runat="server" />
                    </span>! [
                    <asp:LoginStatus ID="MemberLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out"
                        LogoutPageUrl="~/Login.aspx" onloggingout="HeadLoginStatus_LoggingOut" />
                    ]
                </LoggedInTemplate>
            </asp:LoginView>
        </div>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is in your Login.aspx.cs file, there may be setting Authentication Cookies

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that you don't make difference between the following two concepts:

- [ASP.NET Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)
- [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)

Let's me try to elaborate: the ASP.NET session is something that allows to workaround the stateless nature of the HTTP protocol. The server emits a cookie to the client and this cookie is then send by the client on each subsequent request. Then the server associates some information in memory with this cookie. You access this information using the `Session["someKey"]` object. By the default this information is stored in memory although you could configure it to be out of process. So when you rebuild the application or a timeout is reached, the memory on the server is freed and all objects that you have stored disappear. To configure the timeout for the ASP.NET session you could use the following:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="30" />
</system.web>
```

Forms Authentication on the other hand is something completely different. It uses cookies to track authenticated users. This cookie is different than the ASP.NET Session cookie. It has a different timeout value and configured independently:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms
    loginUrl="/login"
    timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

The Forms Authentication mechanism doesn't store anything in the memory of the server. It tracks the authenticated user which is stored inside the cookie. So even if you recompile your application the user is still authenticated for the given timeout period defined in your web.config. Be careful though with the `slidingExpiration` property which renews the timeout on each request.